# hold background color on active selector - css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a treeview to display sidebar nav menu. When ever i click one menu(tree node), there is a light blue background color to show the selected node. But, it is gone when i click again that same node.

I want that background color to stay when it is active till other different node is not selected.Now, i use pseudo classes to solve this but not able to do that.

Is it possible any workaround to stay that background color?

**Code snippet**(TreeView Component)

```
<div
    class="tree-node"
    :class="{
      active: isDragEnterNode,
      'node-selected': model.key === labelSelected ? 'true' : false
    }"
    :id="model.key"
    @mouseover="mouseOver"
    @mouseout="mouseOut"
    @click.stop="click"
    @keydown.enter.stop="click"
    role="presentation"
  > // some code </div>
```

**Css for tree node**

```
.tree-node {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    line-height: 14px;
    padding: 2px 8px 2px 16px;
    cursor: pointer;

    .input {
      border: none;
      max-width: 150px;
      border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
    }
    &:visited {
      background-color: rgba(0, 107, 221, 0.08);
    }

    &:active {
      outline: 2px dashed pink;
      background-color: rgba(0, 107, 221, 0.08);
    }

    .caret {
      margin-left: -16px;
      margin-right: 2px;
      font-size: var(--font-size-x-large);
      flex-grow: 0;
    }

    .operation {
      margin-left: 0;
    }
  }
```

**Screenshot**
[image: 1]

It should be like this till this link is active but this background color is gone after second click.

Comment: try adding this css `&.active {outline: 2px dashed pink;background-color: rgba(0, 107, 221, 0.08);}`

Comment: it is not working.